# Configuring WordPress for Amazon CloudFront Caching?

Tags: cache, cdn

[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is a content distribution network (CDN) that can help you survive a huge amount of load in a short amount of time.  What's the easiest way to configure WordPress to host its files (media library, CSS, plugin files, theme) on S3/CloudFront?

(I'm currently using W3 Total Cache to do this.)

Comment: I was going to answer with http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/ , as far as I know it's the best solution for doing this. What does it lack that you need?

Comment: Yeah, what about W3 Total Cache doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: It wasn't really about me not knowing the answer - it's about documenting the answer for all of humanity. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think the [W3 Total Cache Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) can help you..

Answer (score 3):

The plugin works fine; alternative you can use a own function to replace the bloginf() to your CDN-Url; Example:

replace the url in content:

```
// replace content for CDN
if ( !function_exists('fb_add_static_content_url') ) {
    function fb_add_static_content_url($content) {
            if ( is_admin() ) // eigentlich überflüssig
                return $content;

            $wpurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl');

            $search = array(
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/images/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/download/',
            );

            $replace = array(
                'http://cdn1.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn2.bueltge.de/',
            );

            return str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'fb_add_static_content_url' );
}
```

replace stylesheet_directoy and others:

```
// replace for CDN
if ( !function_exists('fb_add_static_wpurl') ) {
    function fb_add_static_wpurl($info, $show) {

        if ( is_admin() )
            return $info;

        $keys = array(
            'url',
            'wpurl',
            'stylesheet_url',
            'stylesheet_directory',
            'template_url',
            'template_directory',
            );

        if ( in_array( $show, $keys ) ) {

            $wpurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl');

            $search = array(
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/images/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/download/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/themes/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/plugins/',
            );

            $replace = array(
                'http://cdn1.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn2.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn3.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn3.bueltge.de/',
            );

            return str_replace( $search, $replace, $info );

        } else {
            return $info;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'bloginfo_url', 'fb_add_static_wpurl', 9999, 2 );
}
```

replace the template_directory and other:

```
function fb_add_static_stylesheet_uri($uri) {

            if ( is_admin() )
                return $uri;

            $wpurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl');

            $search = array(
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/images/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/download/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/themes/',
                $wpurl . '/wp-content/plugins/',
            );

            $replace = array(
                'http://cdn1.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn2.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn3.bueltge.de/',
                'http://cdn3.bueltge.de/',
            );
            return str_replace( $search, $replace, $uri );

}
add_filter ( 'template_directory_uri', 'fb_add_static_stylesheet_uri' );
add_filter ( 'stylesheet_uri', 'fb_add_static_stylesheet_uri' );
add_filter ( 'stylesheet_directory_uri', 'fb_add_static_stylesheet_uri' );
```